# How to share variables for multiple Programs?

Tags: java, c++, shared-libraries

OK, the title is a bit confusing.

What I have: I have a program M that I cannot modify. I have only the possibility to do some scripting in it and add access to shared objects (DLLs).

Now I want to do some crazy stuff with the data in M. The scripting lnaguage is not sufficient for my needs and I do not want to do everything in the DLL (little experience in C(++),...).

My thought was to create a DLL (lets call it B for bridge) to be inserted in some glue code in M. Now a user application A (in my case written in java) should connect to B. Now the interaction should be possible to connect M with A throug B.

I just tried to conect these things in a example system under linux. Here I run into the problem, that the library does **not** share the needed information.

I have for testing two java instances called J1 and J2. J1 registered a callback functoin in the SO. Triggering the callback from J1 (J1 -> SO -> J1) everything works. Trying to trigger via J2 does not work: It seems J1 to be not registered. Instead J2 get's registeresd. (see sources)

After looking on the net I found:

- It is not trivial to share memory over different processes.
- The behaviour is platform dependent.

Library test code: http://pastebin.com/bFUbwE68 
Java code: http://pastebin.com/zpecisVN

What would you do to get the data from M to A and some data from A to M (frequent polls from M are ok)?

Edit: The long-term goal is running M+B on a virtualized win machine and A connects via network.

Is it better to develop the DLL part directly under Win instead of under Linux and later porting?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a messaging system, such as IBM MQ Series to publish and receive messages between the two application. The JAVA JMS (Java Messaging System) will make it very easy to hook up to a messaging provider.

Comment: How to access Java JMS via C(++)?!? I thought this was pure Java. Or do you mean to use JMS only over the net? Then the question about the communcation between Java and M is still open.

Comment: You don't need to access JMS via C++, you just need to access the messaging system (eg MQ Series) via a C++ wrapper. Every messaging provider will have a C++ interface to their system, and a JMS library for use in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably start with [Java Native Access](https://github.com/twall/jna), if that didn't work I might look at [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). If that didn't work, I'd probably try [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/). If it still wasn't working, I'd probably try [omniORB](http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/) or indeed any other [C++ ORB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORBA). Sorry, you can't use a Windows DLL directly under Linux like that (Windows DLLs are not cross platform). If you're extraordinarily talented and patient you might get it working under emulation [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/). Otherwise, you'll need to use a [RPC mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) such as Thrift or CORBA, or you could go write your own wire protocol (it may sound like a good idea, but it probably isn't), to connect between your Windows machine and Linux machine.

Comment: See the edit; the main problem is to excahnge data between two applications platform independent.

Comment: @ChristianWolf See edit. Linux doesn't natively support Windows DLLs. Are you trying to use a Windows DLL under Linux? By nature Windows DLL files are platform dependent.

Comment: No I was trying to develop the "DLL" (under linux it's a SO) under *nix and later compile the relevant part under windows. As Win is virtualized, it's not that fast in compiling if you know...

Comment: That was my initial assumption. Make your C++ code cross platform and you can just use Java Native Access (or ...).

Comment: And now is the question: How to achive platform independency? Remember, the problem itself is about exchanging data between processes.

Comment: It depends on your requirements. If speed is the number one requirement, don't use a separate process space try and link your Java process to the native library. If you want a flexible runtime - use an RPC or [ESB](http://codebrane.com/blog/2009/07/28/talking-stomp-to-apache-camel-with-c/) or whatever else you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41880/discussion-between-elliott-frisch-and-christian-wolf)

Answer (score -2):

for java you can use a simple variable class that initializes all the variables and creating the singleton object concept you can make the variables globally available to other files in specific project

Comment: How exactly does this answer the question?